# Exclude certain tags while deleting repositories in Azure Container registry

Tags: azure, acr

Is there a way we can exclude deleting certain tags from a Azure container repository and delete rest all tags present.

I have been trying with below command but doesn't seem to work

```
az acr run --registry <myRegistry> --cmd 'acr purge --filter "myRepo.^((?!tag_to_exlude).)*$”’ /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to exclude certain tags from an Azure container registry and delete rest all tags present. The `acr purge` command does not support excluding tags.

However, there is a workaround you can use to achieve the same result:

```c
# Define your Azure Container Registry name and the tag(s) you want to exclude
$registryName = "your-acr-name"
$tagsToExclude = "tag_to_exclude1", "tag_to_exclude2"

# Get a list of repository names in the ACR
$repositories = az acr repository list --name $registryName --output tsv

# Loop through each repository
foreach ($repository in $repositories) {
    # Get a list of all tags in the repository
    $tags = az acr repository show-tags --name $registryName --repository $repository --output tsv

    # Filter tags to exclude the specified ones
    $tagsToDelete = $tags | Where-Object { $tagsToExclude -notcontains $_ }

    # Delete the remaining tags
    foreach ($tag in $tagsToDelete) {
        $imageToDelete = "$($repository):$($tag)"
        az acr repository delete --name $registryName --image $imageToDelete --yes
    }
}
```

[image]

Here as you can see, except `V3` I am deleting rest all version of my tag using the above script:

In my repro I had different tags except v3 I delete all like below:

[image]

After running the script rest all deleted only v3 is left like below:

[image]

In portal:

[image]

Comment: This command deleted everything at one go and moreover I was looking for an option to delete tags excluding few tags from a repo. I don't want the repo to be deleted.

Comment: Could you clear what is your ask ... I have added 4 repositories with tags. here excluding one tag -> `infra/testing2` with tag `v3`  rest all my tags deleted.

Comment: @SOURAVKARMOHAPATRA any update?